# How to get GeoPoint from ArrayList of points?

Tags: java, android, json, gson

Does anybody know how can I convert this

```
"polygon":[{"x":23.5980319,"y":37.9554494},{"x":23.5967015,"y":37.9557201}]
```

to `GeoPoint` using Gson?

Answer (score 1):

```
class ClassA{
     List<Point> polygon;
}

class Point{
    double x;
    double y;
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    String json= "{\"polygon\":[{\"x\":23.5980319,\"y\":37.9554494},{\"x\":23.5967015,\"y\":37.9557201}]}";

    ClassA inpList = new Gson().fromJson(json, ClassA.class);
    for (Point point : inpList.polygon) {
        System.out.println(point.x);
        System.out.println(point.y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Quick answer:** probably you need to write a custom deserializer.

**Detailed answer:** from here to the end.

Two important things before answering.

1. *Your JSON is not valid*. A valid JSON must be an object or a list so starting with `{` or `[`. I leave your JSON string as is, since in 99% of cases, you have not control on string you are trying to parse.
2. `GeoPoint`: I have found *at least 3 different packages* that have this class inside: `org.mapsforge.android.maps.GeoPoint`, `org.andnav.osm.util.GeoPoint` and `com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint`. All of them have in common that there's not a default constructor. They need a couple of doubles or ints to be instantiated. So I created a "fake" GeoPoint class to answer this assuming that you want to work with one of them. If not, the other answer fits well and you do not really need this.

Since you have not a default constructor, best approach with Gson is a custom deserializer. I show you how I solved it with the following code.

```
public class Container {

    public List<GeoPoint> polygon;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Container [polygon=" + polygon + "]";
    }

}
```

and then YAGI (yet another GeoPoint implementation), note that I use a and b as member variable, since I don't make assumption on internals of `GeoPoint` (ie Gson uses reflection to fill fields)

```
public class GeoPoint {
    // this is not a real GeoPoint. Just a stub to avoid importing things
    // I do not want to import to answer!

    double a;
    double b;

    public GeoPoint(Double a, Double b){
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "GeoPoint [x=" + a + ", y=" + b + "]";
    }


}
```

then you need a deserializer (this won't work with `com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint` since it uses int, but you can fit it to your needs in case)

```
public class GeoPointDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<GeoPoint> {

    @Override
    public GeoPoint deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT,
            JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        if (json.isJsonNull())
            return null;

        Double x = json.getAsJsonObject().get("x").getAsDouble();
        Double y = json.getAsJsonObject().get("y").getAsDouble();
        return new GeoPoint(x, y);
    }

}
```

Finally, this code does the job:

```
public class Q1925216 {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String json = "\"polygon\":[{\"x\":23.5980319,\"y\":37.9554494},{\"x\":23.5967015,\"y\":37.9557201}]";

        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(GeoPoint.class, new GeoPointDeserializer());

        Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

        Container c = gson.fromJson("{"+json+"}", Container.class);

        System.out.println(c);
    }

}
```

And this is my execution:

> Container [polygon=[GeoPoint [x=23.5980319, y=37.9554494], GeoPoint
>   [x=23.5967015, y=37.9557201]]]